# Create an internal Network load balancer with AWS Copilot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-nlb, aws-copilot, aws-copilot-cli

I am trying to deploy `bitnami/openldap` container in ECS using AWS Copilot as a backend service with a internal NLB (Couldn't go with ALB since `bitnami/openldap` does not have a http healthcheck endpoint).

I have the following config in Copilot service manifest.

```
name: ldap2023
type: Backend Service

nlb:
  port: 1389/tcp
  healthcheck:
    healthy_threshold: 3
    unhealthy_threshold: 10
    grace_period: 120s
    interval: 15s
    timeout: 10s

network:
  vpc:
    placement: private
```

But when I deploy the service a NLB is not created. R53 dns record is directly pointing to the ECS task ip.

Is it not possible to use NLB with backend service?

Can't find it in [docs](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/manifest/backend-service/) but it is not mentioned that it is [not possible as well](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/developing/internal-albs/). For [Load balanced web service](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/manifest/lb-web-service/) it has examples for both ALB and NLB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current AWS Copilot capability it is not possible to create a internal NLB with backend service.

Possible workaround:

1. create a [Load Balanced Web Service](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/manifest/lb-web-service/) (public NLB)

```
# copilot/<service>/manifest.yml
name: <service name>
type: Load Balanced Web Service
nlb:
  port: 80/tcp
```

2. create a [YAML patch](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/developing/overrides/yamlpatch/) to modify the NLB to internal

```
# copilot/<service>/overrides/cfn.patches.yml
# Change the NLB to internal
- op: replace
  path: /Resources/PublicNetworkLoadBalancer/Properties/Scheme
  value: internal
# Add a Name to the NLB (otherwise the automatically generated name will contain 'public', which is confusing)
- op: add
  path: /Resources/PublicNetworkLoadBalancer/Properties/Name
  value: !Sub "${AppName}-${EnvName}-${WorkloadName}-NLB"
```

Hopefully there will be a feature/option in the future!